# How to remove ambiguity from this syntax (antlr4)

Tags: syntax, antlr

I am writing [a tool](https://www.zenuml.com) to generation sequence diagram from some text. I need to support this two syntax:

1. `anInstance:AClass.DoSomething()` and
2. `participant A -> participant B: Any character except for \r\n (<>{}?)etc.`.

Let's call the fist one `strict` syntax and the second one `free` syntax. In `anInstance:AClass.DoSomething()`, I need it to be matched by `to` ( `ID ':' ID` ) as in the `strict` syntax. However, `:AClass.DoSomething()` will be first matched by `CONTENT`. I am thinking some kind of lookahead, checking if `->` is there but not able to figure it out.

### `Strict` syntax

```
message
 : to '.' signature
 ;
signature
 : methodName '()'
 ;
to
 : ID ':' ID
 ;
methodName
 : ID
 ;

ID
 : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
 ;
```

### `Free` syntax

```
asyncMessage
 : source '->' target content
 ;
source
 : ID+
 ;
target
 : ID+
 ;
content
 : CONTENT
 ;

ID
 : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
 ;
CONTENT
 : ':' ~[\r\n]+
 ;
SPACE
 : [ \t\r\n] -> channel(HIDDEN)
 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand how ANTLR lexer works:

- It uses whichever rule matches the longest part of the input (starting at current position)
- In case multiple rules can match the same input (i.e. same length), the first one (in order they're defined in) is used

With your current lexer rules, `CONTENT` takes precedence whenever you encounter an `:` so `':' ID` will never be matched.

With ANTLR 4, you should probably use *modes* in this case - when you encounter the `:` in the free form, switch to a "free" mode and define a lexer rule `CONTENT` to be only available in the "free" mode.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49733879/antlr-skip-text-outside-tag) for an idea about how ANTLR 4 lexer modes work.